# Taskwarrior (task reminder) applet

Tags: indicator, evolution, applet, task-management

I am trying to find a way how to integrate [taskwarrior](http://taskwarrior.org/) (aka [task](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=task)) reminders into unity and I understand the [clock applet](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Applets) in ubuntu shows tasks from [`evolution-data-server`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=evolution-data-server).
Is there a way to switch task/calendar sources, or an "easy" way to write my own applet for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a bare-bones indicator is simple.  My `indicator-fortune` [here](http://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+archive/ppa) will give you a first step into writing a Python 3 (and GTK+ 3) indicator.  There's a multitude of indicators [listed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available) which will give you other examples.

The hard part is figuring out how to connect to *taskwarrior* - does it have an API or some way to send/receive information which is accessed via your indicator?  Would you instead parse it's config/data files (it that's what it uses)?

Your first step might be (after getting the vanilla indicator running) to simply display information from *taskwarrior*, so the indicator is read-only.  After that you might then push your luck and see if you can send data back from the indicator.